# php curl access to website with cloudflare 2021

Tags: php, curl, cloudflare

I have been parsing sites for years using curl, but i'm having some unknown stuff about a website. Checking what ir returns it uses cloudfires and investigating about it i saw that it use some kind of mechanism to ignore bots but allow users.

What i dont understand i how it is able to do that, since it returns 403 code before any sending but if i do the same with chrome it works fine.

I have tested the "curl to bash and command line options" from chrome's inspector with the same result

this is the code that i'm using:

```
$headers=array(
    'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1',
    //'Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    //'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
    );
    
    $agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36";


$url="https://www.pccomponentes.com/";

//$agent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
$agent = 'facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)';

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 360); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH, 1); 
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TCP_NODELAY, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
echo "code: ".curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE ).PHP_EOL;
//echo $result;
```

And you can see in comments i have checke a lot of different solutions, different agents, different curl options but i get always a 403 code.

curl command line sh code is

```
curl -I -vvv 'https://www.pccomponentes.com/' \
  -H 'authority: www.pccomponentes.com' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: none' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9' \
  --compressed
```

To check with google chrome i open a secure window with not cookies at all, and then i open inspector and i write the url.

the output of the script (it is the same with command-line curl) is

```
*   Trying 104.16.162.71:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.pccomponentes.com (104.16.162.71) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=CA; L=San Francisco; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=sni.cloudflaressl.com
*  start date: Aug 11 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 11 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.pccomponentes.com" matched cert's "*.pccomponentes.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Cloudflare, Inc.; CN=Cloudflare Inc ECC CA-3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0xaaab008552b0)
> GET /listado/ajax?idShops%5B%5D=0&page=0&order=price-desc&gtmTitle=Tarjetas%20Gr%C3%A1ficas&idFamilies%5B%5D=6 HTTP/2
Host: www.pccomponentes.com
user-agent: facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1

* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 256)!
< HTTP/2 403 
< date: Sat, 01 May 2021 09:28:32 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< cf-chl-bypass: 1
< set-cookie: __cfduid=db6d6b293bbc3a77fe7f7b90ec55cebc31619861312; expires=Mon, 31-May-21 09:28:32 GMT; path=/; domain=.pccomponentes.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
< cache-control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
< x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
< cf-request-id: 09c8db2a8c0000611f910c2000000001
< expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< server: cloudflare
< cf-ray: 6487faf0d82d611f-BCN
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.pccomponentes.com left intact
code: 403
```

I have been searching information for:

- old SSL session ID is stale, removing

but no luck.

What kind of protection is it using?, i saw something about js but it is not even loaded when it is already returning a 403 code. I saw some comments about catpcha but thats not possible before any sending.. chrome is returning code 200 and curl 403.

I have tried with HTTP/1.1 too, with different enconding, with gzip, etc... no luck at all.

It seems that they changed the system recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cloudflare examines the headers and requests it receives to determine if the sender is a robot
You can send your request even without any headers and additional items, if the server side is not checked, there is no problem, but in the cases that are checked, you should try to make your requests as similar as the request requested by the client. The browser will be sent

This is the default answer for the first time you open the page In the browser, if you open it for the first time, the result is 403 But next time it is not like this because of the cookies You can use the same cookies in your request

[image]

for test :
You can delete your desired cookie And reload the page For the first time, if you do not have a cookie, you will encounter 403 and captcha again

[image]

**Example:**

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.pccomponentes.com/",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
        'x-application-type: WebClient',
        'x-client-version: 2.10.4',
        'Origin: https://www.googe.com',
        'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0',
    ]
];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

[image]

The request you send from php does not have a cookie, so you will always encounter 403 You can use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to use cookies in php with curl

https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html

Comment: no, you are getting 403, just add echo "code: ".curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE ).PHP_EOL; before the curl_close, ti is not the webpage, it is other content.

Comment: 403 with that webpage, thats wrong, if you do the same with chrome as i said, you get a 200 code.

Comment: It is what i asked, how is it possible to detect you as bot before anything..

Comment: it's true
  This is the default answer for the first time you open the page
In the browser, if you open it for the first time, the result is 403
But next time it is not like this because of the cookies
You can use the same cookies in your request

Comment: You can delete your desired cookie
And reload the page
For the first time, if you do not have a cookie, you will encounter 403 and captcha again

Comment: The request you send from php does not have a cookie, so you will always encounter 403
You can use CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE to use cookies in php with curl

Comment: but cookies will expire after a while and i then it is useless for an script. Anywyays as i said in hidden mode opening the webpage you dont directly a return code 200, as i said, cloning that request from curl (it is possible with chrome) you get a different value.

Comment: Cookies are updated each time they are used, and this is what causes them
You can do this using CURL and cookies are automatically updated on requests
It is not different from the browser. In the browser, open the page without a cookie, you will encounter 403 again.

Comment: I have used lynx to get a valid cookie, after that i use that cooking for curl, and still getting 403. It is not working

Comment: @hamboy75 I have same problem that you. Could you solved it?

Comment: @defekas17 no :(. The only way to work with this is to use a compiled by you browser where you can simulate some human stuff.. that was that i had in mind but didnt try

Comment: ```cloudflare examines the headers and requests it receives to determine if the sender is a robot``` - that's not all, nowadays Cloudflare also examines subtle differences in the TLS implementation of the client, to detect if it's libcurl-or-not-libcurl, i don't remember the exact details, but even if the header and request is 100% identical, cloudflare can still tell from the TLS negotiation if its libcurl-based or not.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is SSL/TLS incompatibility. Cloudflare started checking the SSL negotiation stage (before any request/response) and match it against common variations of header/certificate combos. You can read more about it here:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/monsters-in-the-middleboxes/

Since you are not using SSL at all, that's immediate red flag for them. But even if you do use it, it must match 1:1 to real browser and user agent.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Use Postman extension and desktop app to capture request headers and cookies

2 - Use this function and replace user agent to yours

```
function fecthElement($url = ''){
$url = $url == '' ? 'https://google.com/' : $url;
// get cookie
$headers = array(
    // cookies
    "Cookie: key=value",
    "Cookie: key2=value2",
    "Cookie: key3=value3",
    // other headers
    'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"',
    'DNT: 1',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1',
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0..... YOUR USER AGENT', // change it
    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document',
    'host: google.com',
);

$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $output;}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the Same issue. I tried with Postman (Chrome Extention, NOT the Desktop Tool)
and it worked
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=de

The Desktop Version will not Work, only the Extention

Comment: How would that extension work with PHP?